# Javascript Regex to replace a sub directory in url

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a sub directory in a URL that comes after a specific directory:

then append a directory to the matched string.

`/applications/app1` should be `/applications/app1/beta`

`/applications/app2/` should be `/applications/app2/beta/`

`/applications/app2/settings` should be `/applications/app2/beta/settings`

`/applications/app3?q=word` should be `/applications/app3/beta?q=word`

I wrote this:

`path = path.replace(/(\/applications\/(.*)(\/|\s|\?))/, '$1/beta');`

But doesn't work if the app-name is in the end of the string.

**Note:** I don't have the app name I only know that it follows `/applications/`

Comment: Take care that after you replace `/applications/app2/settings` with `/applications/app2/beta/settings`, it is easy to fall into the abyss by replacing `/applications/app2/beta/settings` with `/applications/app2/beta/beta/settings` which becomes `/applications/app2/beta/beta/beta/settings`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
path.replace(/(\/applications\/[^/?]+)/g,'$1/beta');
```

After some consideration, I prefer the following:

```
path.replace(/(\/applications\/[^/?]+)($|\/|\?)(?!beta)/g,'$1/beta$2');

"/applications/app1/beta"      -> "/applications/app1/beta"
"/applications/app1"           -> "/applications/app1/beta"
"/applications/app1/settings"  -> "/applications/app1/beta/settings"
"/applications/app1?q=123"     -> "/applications/app1/beta?q=123"
```

It will ignore `/applications/beta` when matching.

Comment: @Joe Hany Updated answer

Comment: Thank you @BGerrissen just place /beta after the app name

Comment: @Joe Hany There you go ;)